# Error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS while loading Lightning App

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

I'm getting **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** error in browser console while opening the lightning app. This doesn't affect the functionality though, it is making delay in loading completion of the app. I'm making one call to Apex class to populate records through "**Init**". Any suggestions to improve loading time or any idea about what this error is about? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "opening the lightning app", you mean you are going to your custom app's URL? (EX: myorg/myapp.app) Or is this a tab in the Salesforce1 app? Is there anything else in the browser console? My suspicion is this may be some beta growing pains.

Comment: @Peter. It is going to the app through URL. I'm getting this error twice during the navigation to the app URL.

Comment: No known "growing pains" like this currently being tracked. Vignex can you provide a repro case with specific instructions - what you have provided so far is insufficient info for me to act on.

Comment: what instance are you on?

Comment: Can you show us your init code?

Answer (score 1):

The last time that I encountered this was when there was a stored site setting in my chrome browser. After clearing the site setting and allowing third party cookies in chrome, this cleared right up. The issue is that the stored setting stored an old session token in a cookie that had since changed. So what it was doing was attempting to acquire a new one and Chrome was persisting the cookie and blocking the new values. My settings now look like this:

[image]

After this change, I have never seen this again. I regularly log in to at least 8 different instances a day and each one loads very fast without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem today while using chrome (v.43.0.2357.130 m) while trying out the Trailhead tutorials on lightning components. I managed to workaround it by using a different browser, or by starting a new browser session in chrome (e.g. forcing incognito mode and logging in again). Hope this helps somebody with the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this a few times. I can think of 2 things:

1. It's possible you have circular reference in your client-side code somewhere.
2. I would suggest looking at the Debug Console and seeing what APEX code
   is actually being executed to make sure that it's really only
   running once, and that it's not causing some error.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue too, I needed to set up a domain (for eg; your name.instance.salesforce.com) and if that doesn't work you should also try to run it in incognito as @topealvim mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could fix the issue I was having with Conga (different app same error message) via salesforce settings

In the setup menu > security >  Session Setting

Update the following

- Adding the visual force page to the **Trusted Domains**
- and by also checking "Enable XSS protection" checkbox on that page

(just make sure to hit save on the bottom of the page)